# Delete/Remove group from AD

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, adsi

I am using this script to add/create a new group:

```
$strCLass = "Group"
$StrName = "CN=$naam"
$intGroupType = $type
$objADSI = [ADSI]"LDAP://ou=$OU,dc=myADserver,dc=local" 
$objGroup = $objADSI.create($strCLass, $StrName)
$ObjGroup.put("GroupType",$intGroupType)
$objGroup.setInfo()
```

I can't find a way to reverse this so that i can delete group from the OU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$objADSI.Delete($strCLass,$StrName)
```

Comment: This is useful on servers which have an older version of Powershell that doesn't have the Powershell ActiveDirectory module available.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the Powershell ActiveDirectory module?

If you can, then it's as simple as `Remove-ADGroup`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617228.aspx